# AngularJS ng-disable functionality within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, button

I currently have two arrays of objects made in my javascript. The first array named list1 has keys named show and number, a boolean and integer. The second array named list2 has a key named number that takes on an integer.

I currently have a button that will add a number from `list1` to `list2`, and I want to disable it the number already exists in `list2`.

Here is the HTML only showing repeat (my controller is renamed to list)

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list.list1>
   <a href="#" 
      class="btn btn-info btn-large" 
      ng-disabled=!"item.show" 
      ng-click="list.addItem(id, $index)">

      Add
   </a>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
this.addItem = function(id, index)
{
   this.list1[index].show = false;

   this.list2.push({number: id})
};
```

I'm not sure why my code isn't working and this isn't the first implementation I've tried. Would really appreciate some tips on how to do this correctly.  Thanks!

Sorry about the bad initial code, sleepless night hasn't really helped me debug this.

Comment: What is the index in list1[index]?

Comment: Forgot to include $index in the function, updated code to reflect changes

Comment: Is `list` the alias for your controller? And what is `pmt`?

Comment: I think what you have posted now should work except for the incorrect placement of `!` in the `ng-disable` attribute

Comment: Sorry, just updated code, it's still not working for me.  Any idea on another implementation?

Comment: I recommend putting this up on plunkr or jsfiddle and posting a link.   You will get much faster and better help that way.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: So what is the problem? No where in your code you are setting `pmt.show` to be `false`. So why do you expect the button to be disabled if you are not changing the variable?

Comment: @Kousha `addItem` should update the value of `show` to `false`. Though, over the course of several edits, there is now a new issue introduce where the `pmt` variable is no longer defined. It was in the first few iterations of this question.

Answer (score 1):

From your code for `addItem`, it looks like each entry in `list1` has a property named `show`, rather than the array having a property named `show`. If that's the case, then your anchor should look something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-large" ng-disabled="!pmt.show" ng-click="list.addItem(id, $index)">Add</a>
```

Also, the `!` operator should be within the quotes on `ng-disabled`.

Comment: +1, although I think there may be other problems.  E.g. what is list.pmt?  Is addItem in a service, and is the repeat binding to the correct scope?

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried that before but I still couldn't get it working, that's definitely what I meant to write in my question

Comment: I think your right @PhilSandler, looks like there are multiple issues here and the posted code doesn't give us enough to really troubleshoot this

Comment: Sorry updated code, had trouble sleeping last night and it's taking a toll on my ability to focus

Comment: No problem @user3821516, we've all had those days :) And welcome to StackOverflow!